# JOIN not equals?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've been having an issue.

What the following code does is grab the details from the first table, only if the criteria from the second matches (and excludes the current member [player_id] from the query [WHERE]).

What I need it to do is to grab the data from the first table, excluding the users from the second table.

So if the Player has already matched with the User, exclude that from the results; **it should be a list of previously unmatched users**.

*Matches only exist after the event, so it needs to check if there has/not been a match.*

I thought using <> in the JOIN would be enough, but it doesn't work, and old threads say to use OUTER, but that doesn't work either.  LEFT JOIN doesn't exclude and RIGHT JOIN returns the same as JOIN.

```
SELECT
    a.user_id,
    b.*
FROM
    tblUsers a
        JOIN tblMatches b
            ON (b.player_1 = ". $player_id ." AND b.player_2 = a.user_id)
            OR (b.player_2 = ". $player_id ." AND b.player_1 = a.user_id)
WHERE
    a.user_id <> ". $player_id ."
GROUP BY
    a.user_id
```

Update of sample data:

- tblUsers, literally a list of User IDs (1, 2, 3, 4, etc).
- tblMatches, one user ID and another user ID (1 & 3, 2 & 3, 4 & 1, etc.)

Comment: It sounds like you might be looking for a LEFT JOIN but for null in the condition on the table to exclude. It would help if you could add to your question a sample of rows from both tables together with a sample of what you would expect the query output to be given the input sample.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski so LEFT JOIN rather than just JOIN, and WHERE would be, b.player_1 and 2 IS NULL?

Comment: Maybe - can you also add an example of what the exact query output would be for the table samples you added? (it helps to format them as tables too)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski TBH, I don't know how to format them as tables.  But you was right in your suggestion.  More than happy to mark your answer as correct :-)

Comment: If you've already added your own answer what worked for you, I won't bother contributing an equivalent one. Be sure to return tomorrow and mark your own accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, yes... what Michael Berkowski said, LEFT JOIN and IS NULL.

This is my updated code:

```
SELECT
    a.user_id,
    b.*
FROM
    $wpdb->usermeta a
        LEFT JOIN wp_matches b
            ON (b.player_1 = ". $player_id ." AND b.player_2 = a.user_id)
            OR (b.player_2 = ". $player_id ." AND b.player_1 = a.user_id)
WHERE
    b.player_1 IS NULL AND b.player_2 IS NULL
GROUP BY
    a.user_id
```

A few tweaks needed to include further conditions, but I am excluding any matched users now.

Comment: There is no problem in sql for which the above is a solution :-(

Comment: What do you mean @Strawberry

Comment: I mean this returns an indeterminate result. In the absence of any aggregating functions, one never needs a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I see what you mean.  Normally, yes, GROUP BY is not needed, but in this instance it is because of how the database is structured.

There is more data which is needed, and rather than have it on one row, it is split over many rows.  GROUP BY simply pulls it all together.

Comment: That's fine, but just to note that, in this instance, the result returned is essentially meaningless.

Comment: Duly noted. Verily.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the users that haven't played against the player from the variable?
Then a NOT EXISTS could help with that.

Something like this:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM tblUsers u
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM tblMatches m
    WHERE @player_id IN (m.player_1, m.player_2)
      AND u.user_id IN (m.player_1, m.player_2)
)
```